# Nuxt with composition api - access to root instance in composition function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, es6-modules, vue-composition-api

I have an external api file for api calls. My axios instance is bound to the main nuxt (or vue) instance.

If setup() was in my component I could get access to it with **setup(props, context)**

but how can I access this in an external composition function?

````
import { reactive} from '@vue/composition-api'


export default function api() {
 
//do some axios stuff ```
````

Answer (score 1):

In your setup() function in where you are importing/using it pass it into your function.

```
import  api  from '@/use/api'
  
setup(_, { root }) {
  
const { api } = api(root)
```

and in your composition function

```
export default function api(root) {
```